# heroku plugin, how to access an env variable like RAILS_ENV?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm in the process of building a rails plugin to automate my teams deployment process.. Problem is I can't find a way to access teh rails env variable. I have the following:

```
config = YAML.load(File.open("#{Dir.getwd}/config/s3.yml"))[RAILS_ENV]
```

That errors with:

```
in `const_missing_from_s3_library': uninitialized constant Heroku::Command::Jammit::RAILS_ENV (NameError)
```

Anyone know how? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `Rails.env` instead of `RAILS_ENV` with Rails 3 and up. Try using:

```
config = YAML.load(File.open("#{Dir.getwd}/config/s3.yml"))[Rails.env]
```

Or this if you get scope issues with just `Rails`:

```
config = YAML.load(File.open("#{Dir.getwd}/config/s3.yml"))[::Rails.env]
```

Comment: @AnApprentice: That should work in any Rails 3 environment. The error message is telling you that there is no `RAILS_ENV` constant defined, the `Rails` class should be available so it should work.

Comment: That gives an error 'uninitialized constant Heroku::Command::Railgun::Rails (NameError)' is there something I need to require to get Rails.env to return on heroku as a plugin? I tried  require 'rails/all'

Comment: @AnApprentice: How about `::Rails.env`?